# Javascript For Loop On Array of Input fields issue with document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, arrays, getelementbyid

I have an serverside script making an amount of text fields for me.  When I want a user to fill them up, and submit data.  I know how many fields there are, as the server also sends a count.

I am then trying to join them into a long string with a spacer between.  But I am having trouble getting the value of the array.

Better explained with code.

This works

```
        <script>
function Submit() {
    var spacer = ":";
    var mycount = document.getElementById('counter').value;
    var usertext = '';
    var x=0;
    for(x = 0; x **<= 2**; x++){
        usertext = usertext + document.getElementById('description[' + x + ']').value + spacer ;
    }
</script>
```

This does not work.

```
    <script>
function Submit() {
    var spacer = ":";
    var mycount = document.getElementById('counter').value;
    var usertext = '';
    var x=0;
    for(x = 0; x **<= mycount**; x++){
        usertext = usertext + document.getElementById('description[' + x + ']').value + spacer ;
    }
</script>
```

This is my body

```
    <textarea   id='counter' name='counter'>2</textarea>
<textarea   id='description[0]' name=''description'>zero</textarea>
<textarea   id='description[1]' name=''description'>one</textarea>
<textarea   id='description[2]' name=''description'>two</textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="Submit()" >Save</button>
```

This is the error Firebug gives me:

> document.getElementById("description["
>   + x + "]") is null

Does anyone know a way to do this?

thanks

Comment: Note sure if it is relevant to the problem, but you have a problem with the quotes in here: `name=''description'`. Note the double single quote before "description".

Comment: d'oh.. fixed, but didnt help my issue.

Answer (score 1):

It [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/4XhED/3/) for me despite your invalid HTML (e.g. unbalanced quotes).  The better question is what the purpose of this is.  Why not just submit the form as is?

Comment: that JS Fiddle is a cool tool, didnt know it existed.

It works for me also in that tool, but copy that same code locally, and I cant get it to work in IE, FF or Chrome.

Why, because I actually have to output it for a legacy app.

Comment: @greg, we need a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to be able to help.  Post a simple complete page that shows the issue.

Comment: wow, so in the process of making a SSCCE, I somehow fixed it.  But no idea how.  If I work it out, I will post.  Weird.  thanks guy

Answer (score 1):

Before applying `mycount` to a for loop take the integer value of `mycount` with `parseInt`:

```
var mycount = document.getElementById('counter').value;
mycount = parseInt(mycount);
```